# How do app servers inject into private fields?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations

I saw this question

[Inject into private, package or public field or provide a setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021716/inject-into-private-package-or-public-field-or-provide-a-setter)

about how to manually inject into annotated private fields (The way is adding setters
or through a constructor)

But, the point is how do an application server (like glassfish, axis2, jboss, ...)
is able to inject into a final private field (without adding setters or constructors
to the user class)?

Quoting the cited question:

```
public SomeClass {
  @Inject
  private SomeResource resource;
}
```

Do they use a customized JVM (not the standard one) that allows to access private fields?

Thanks

Comment: This is private, but not final. Did you miss *final* in the code block? Because i don't think it's possible to inject private final members. (Correct me if i'm wrong.)

Comment: @Willi : You're right. In the code sample below I put final, but even no error was raised by the doInjection() method the value did not change. So I removed final.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a simple reflection "trick". It relies on the [`Field.setAccessible()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) method to force the member to be accessible programmatically:

> Set the accessible flag for this
>   object to the indicated boolean value.
>   A value of true indicates that the
>   reflected object should suppress Java
>   language access checking when it is
>   used. A value of false indicates that
>   the reflected object should enforce
>   Java language access checks.

The Reflection API is used to get a handle on the field, `setAccessible()` is called, and then it can be set by the injection framework.

See an example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080511181935/http://radio.javaranch.com/val/2004/05/18/1084891793000.html).

No magic, no custom VM.

Answer (score 6):

With the help of skaffman I coded this simple example on how to inject without setters.
Perhaps it helps (It did to me)

```
//......................................................
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

//......................................................
@Target(value = {ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Inject {
}

//......................................................
class MyClass {

    @Inject
    private int theValue = 0;

    public int getTheValue() {
        return theValue;
    }
} // class

//......................................................
public class Example {

    //......................................................
    private static void doTheInjection(MyClass u, int value) throws IllegalAccessException {

        Field[] camps = u.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        System.out.println("------- fields : --------");
        for (Field f : camps) {
            System.out.println(" -> " + f.toString());
            Annotation an = f.getAnnotation(Inject.class);
            if (an != null) {
                System.out.println("       found annotation: " + an.toString());
                System.out.println("       injecting !");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                f.set(u, value);
                f.setAccessible(false);
            }
        }

    } // ()

    //......................................................
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MyClass u = new MyClass();

        doTheInjection(u, 23);

        System.out.println(u.getTheValue());

    } // main ()
} // class
```

Run output:

```
------- fields : --------
 -> private int MyClass.theValue
       found annotation: @Inject()
       injecting !
23
```

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth noting, that some frameworks utilize bytecode engineering via a custom classloader to achieve the same result without the cost of Reflection (reflection can be pretty expensive at times)