# How to solve NullPointerException when Autowiring component in spring-boot application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, autowired, vaadin-flow

When autowiring a component, in this case a @Service, I get a BeanInstantiationException from a NullPointerException.

I am using annotation based bean creation, from what I understand all needed is to annotate the class with @Service, @Repository, @Component or @Controller.
I have tried scanning the packages and classes separately and combined, and am using @EnableJpaRepositories on the repository package.

The application:

```
package com.demoApp;


import com.demoApp.backend.DAOs.UserDAO;
import com.demoApp.backend.domain.User;
import com.demoApp.backend.services.Services;
import com.demoApp.ui.views.MainView;
import com.demoApp.app.security.SecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

/**
 * Spring boot web application initializer.
 */
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = { SecurityConfiguration.class, MainView.class, admexFront.class,
        UserDAO.class, Services.class}, exclude = ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class,scanBasePackages = {"com.demoApp.backend.services"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.demoApp.backend.DAOs"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.demoApp.backend.domain"})
public class admexFront extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(admexFront.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(admexFront.class);
    }
}
```

And here is the Services helper class:

```
package com.demoApp.backend.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.SessionScope;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Service(value = "Services")
@SessionScope
public class Services implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public ContactService getContactService() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(ContactService.class);
    }

    public UserService getUserService() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class);
    }
}
```

Here is the ContactView route in which the error occurs:

```
package com.demoApp.ui.views;

import com.demoApp.app.security.SecurityUtils;
import com.demoApp.backend.domain.Client;
import com.demoApp.backend.domain.Contact;
import com.demoApp.backend.domain.User;
import com.demoApp.backend.services.Services;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.FlexComponent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.List;

@Tag("contact-view")
@Route(value = "contacts", layout = MenuBar.class)
public class ContactView extends Div {


    public static String NAME = "Contacts";
    public static String ROUTE = "contacts";
    public static String ICON = "arrow-right";

    private VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    @Autowired
    private Services services;

    @Autowired
    public ContactView() {
        User loggedInUser = SecurityUtils.getUser();

        Contact userContact = loggedInUser.getContactRef();
        Client client = userContact.getClientRef();


        mainLayout.setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.AUTO);
        add(mainLayout);


        List<Contact> contacts = services.getContactService().getAllContactsFromClient(client);

        Grid<Contact> contactGrid = new Grid<>(Contact.class);
        contactGrid.setColumns("Contact Code", "Name", "Email");

        add(contactGrid);

    }
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.demoApp.ui.views.ContactView': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [co
m.demoApp.ui.views.ContactView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Since the exception is thrown in your `ContactView`, you should probably include that. Without seeing that, my guess would be that you use field injection but try to access the autowired field in the constructor. Please try using [constructor injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737720/constructor-injection-vs-field-injection) instead and tell me how that went.

Comment: I agree with @kaspar since the error is from ContactView, can't identify without seeing this file. issue with constructor

Comment: Thanks, added the `ContactView` class as well

Comment: There are many things wrong with this design.  I suggest you understand the Model View Controller pattern.  Also understand what Dependency Injection is and how Spring can be used for it.

Comment: Another thanks @Kaspar - it did solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put yourself in Spring's shoes. It has to contruct a `ContactView`, and populate its `services` field.

To be able to populate the field of the object, the object needs to exist, right? So it has to call the constructor to construct the object, **before** being able to set its field. So, when the constructor is called, the field can't possibly be populated yet, and is thus null. Hence the NullPointerException, since you call a method on the field inside the constructor.

Solution: don't use field injection. Use constructor injection.

```
// NO @Autowired here
private Services services;

@Autowired // this is actually optional unless you have another constructor
public ContactView(Services services) {
    this.services = services;
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explaination - this solved it!