# How to make a simple rest api controller test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, controller, spring-test

So I am trying to make a test for the post method of my controller, but I keep finding tests from other people that do not work on my or their post methods are way more advanced.

**My post method**

```
@Autowired
PartyLeaderService partyleaderService;

@PostMapping("/")
public void add(@RequestBody PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto){
    partyLeaderService.savePartyLeader(partyLeaderDto);
}
```

As you can see it is fairly simple, but I still can not seem to get it to work properly.
I tried this method:

```
@Test
public void testPostExample() {
    PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto = new PartyLeaderDto(1, "arun", "link");

    partyLeaderController.add(partyLeaderDto);
    Mockito.verify(partyLeaderController).add(partyLeaderDto);
}
```

But SonarQube is saying that the method is still not covered by tests, so my test must be wrong.

**My DTO**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class PartyLeaderDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String apperance;
}
```

Can anyone help me, because I think the answer is fairly simple, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your unit test is that you're verifying a call over something that is not a mock

```
Mockito.verify(partyLeaderController).add(partyLeaderDto);
```

partyLeaderController is not a mock as this is what you're looking to test at the moment.
What you should be mocking and verifying is `PartyService`.

```
  @Test
  public void testPostExample() {
    PartyService partyService = mock(PartyService.class);
    PartyLeaderController controller = new PartyLeaderController(partyService);
    PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto = new PartyLeaderDto(1, "arun", "link");

    controller.add(partyLeaderDto);
    
    Mockito.verify(partyService).saveParty(partyLeaderDto);
  }
```

However this is not a very good approach to test the web layer, as what you should be looking to cover with your test is not only whether `PartyService` is called but also that you're exposing an endpoint in a given path, this endpoint is expecting the POST method, it's expecting an object (as json perhaps?) and it's returning a status code (and maybe a response object?)

An easy, unit test-like approach to cover this is to use MockMvc.

```
  @Test
  public void testPostExample() {
    PartyService partyService = mock(PartyService.class);
    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new PartyLeaderController(partyService)).build();
    PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto = new PartyLeaderDto(1, "arun", "link");

    mockMvc.perform(
        post("/party")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(partyLeaderDto))
    ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    verify(partyService).saveParty(partyLeaderDto);
  }
```

Comment: I am getting the following error on this line:
 MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new PartyLeaderController(partyService))
Expected 0 arguments but found 1
My controller does not have a constructor. Should I make one with the service in it?

Comment: Also when I edit that line to this:
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new PartyLeaderController());
I get the following error:
Required type:
MockMvc
Provided:
StandaloneMockMvcBuilder

Comment: Yes, it's recommended to use constructor injection vs field-level injection, one of the key benefits of this is that it's easier to test :) here's some referrence about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737720/constructor-injection-vs-field-injection

Comment: Oops, I forgot .build() at the end, will edit my answer.

Comment: Now this is the next error I get: Wanted but not invoked:
partyLeaderService.savePartyLeader(
    com.example.demo.DTO.PartyLeaderDto@3136e15a
);
-> at com.example.demo.Controller.PartyLeaderEndpointTests.testPostExample(PartyLeaderEndpointTests.java:97)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: That sounds like the test doing its work, means your method is not being called. If you blindly copied the code I gave, then I think you need to replace post("/party") with the path where your endpoint is exposed, perhaps it's just post("/") ?

Comment: Nope I checked that and that is not the problem

Comment: Debug the unit test and place a breakpoint in your controller's method, should be quite easy to identify whether your method is being called and this method is calling partyService.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232517/discussion-between-lardinoisjosse-and-yayotron).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is actually a unit test by verifying a stub call.

Either you can unit test by mocking the behaviour using Mockito's when(....).then(...) and then using assertion to assert the results.

or
You can follow this article to use a MockMvc to do an integration test step by step-
https://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Yayotron I got to the answer.
This is the code:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser("Test User")
public void testPostParty() throws Exception {
    PartyLeaderService partyLeaderService = mock(PartyLeaderService.class);
    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new PartyLeaderController(partyLeaderService)).build();
    PartyLeaderDto partyLeaderDto = new PartyLeaderDto(1, "arun", "link");

    mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("http://localhost:8080/partyleaders/")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(partyLeaderDto))
    ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    Mockito.verify(partyLeaderService).savePartyLeader(ArgumentMatchers.refEq(partyLeaderDto));
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping!