# How to create services objects from Camunda process Engine?

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, bpmn, business-process-management, camunda-modeler

How you create Objects like `userService` or `taskService` from process engine in Camunda?
my way is this:

```
@Inject
private TaskService taskService;
```

or

```
ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine().getTaskService();
```

Is there a better or more correct way for large projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply injecting the service you need in the bean is fine. It is the simplest way and gives you the benefits of Spring Beans.

Prefer constructor based injection over field injection (e.g. [Constructor injection vs Field injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737720/constructor-injection-vs-field-injection)) for easier testing and detection for cyclic dependencies.

Comment: What Rob said!   Plus: consider preferring constructor injection over field injection, this way your Beans dependencies are defined in a clearer way and testing becomes much easier.