# How to execute the code of a used Component instead @Mock the results in JUnit Tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

I have a `@Component` class that contains some `@Inject` components to perform some code logic. In my Test, I would like to execute that logic instead Mock the results. I don't want to import `spring-boot-starter-test` because will overload the dependencies and generate conflicts.

The `Service1` and `Service2` doesn't use any third services, it's has just executed simple logic.

```
@Component
public class MainService {

    @Inject
    private Service1 service1;

    @Inject 
    private Service2 service2;

}
 
---------------- Test Class ----------------

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @Mock
    private Service1 service1;

    @Mock
    private Service2 service2;

    @InjectMocks
    private MainService mainService;

    @Before
    public void startUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
       Mockito.when(service1.function).thenReturn(...); 
       Mockito.when(service2.function).thenReturn(...);
       // How to provide real execution instead Mock the results?

       mainService.start();
       // asserts...
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to inject actual instances of service1 and service2 fields into the mainService in your test class?

Comment: @Jonasz exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be just using the constructor or accessor injection instead of field injection (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381846/why-use-constructor-over-setter-injection-in-cdi) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39892204/3305737)), but if you really need to stick to the field injection, simply replace the `@Mock` annotations with `@Spy` annotations like so:

```java
@Spy
private Service1 service1;
@Spy
private Service2 service2;
```

or (if the `ServiceX` classes do not have a default constructor):

```java
@Spy
private Service1 service1 = new Service1(...);
@Spy
private Service2 service2 = new Service2(...);
```

Those fields will be used by Mockito when you call `initMocks` and will be injected into the fields annotated with `@InjectMocks`. No behavior mocking required, the actual `ServiceX` classes code will be called.

---

I've prepared a fully reproducible code example in [a GitHub repository here](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/73322701/spring-boot-module/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz/SomeTest.java) - the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use real instances of `service1` and `service2` you can use [@Spy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39197040/19739158)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).