# Mock out class nested inside classes for testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

Alpha - parent with beta as child

```
public class Alpha {
  Beta beta;

  public Alpha(int argument) {}

  void start() {
    beta = createBeta();
  }

  Beta createBeta() {
    return new Beta(this);
  }
}
```

Beta - child of alpha, has charlie

```
public class Beta {
  Alpha alpha;
  Charlie charlie;

  public Beta(Alpha alpha) {
    this.alpha = alpha;
    this.charlie = createCharlie();
  }

  Charlie createCharlie() {
    return new Charlie().shuffle();
  }
}
```

Charlie - has a list, which is usually shuffled in production

```
public class Charlie {
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public Charlie() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      list.add(i);
    }
  }

  public Charlie shuffle() {
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return list.toString();
  }
}
```

AlphaTest **[need help with this test]** - want to try different variations of shuffling to see how alpha/beta would react.

```
public class AlphaTest {

  Charlie special = new Charlie();

  @Test
  public void testSpecialCharlie() {
    Alpha alpha = Mockito.spy(new Alpha(0));
    Beta beta = Mockito.spy(alpha.createBeta());

    Mockito.when(alpha.createBeta()).thenReturn(beta);
    Mockito.when(beta.createCharlie()).thenReturn(special);

    alpha.start();

    // FAILURE: expected:<[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]> but was:<[0, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2]>
    assertEquals(special.list, alpha.beta.charlie.list);
  }
}
```

Goal is to test Alpha/Beta with different combinations of Charlie. Not sure what's the best way to do that? This is exact code copied. Open to changing the setup also to facilitate testing. Tried different variations, nothing really working. Would really appreciate help with this.

I am not sure, I tried a bunch of ways (mocking out `createCharlie()` function, mocking out `Charlie` class, mocking out `shuffle()`, moving `createCharlie()` to parent `Alpha` class, nothing really works properly or maybe I was missing something. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Wonder why I can't just do this:

```
Charlie charlie = Mockito.mock(Charlie.class);
Mockito.when(charlie.shuffle()).thenReturn(special);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing really works properly"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, I couldn't get it to work, I am really new to testing, so I probably wasn't doing right. I am okay restructuring the setup a little bit also. Please let me know how you would do this? Thanks!

Comment: Unit testing code like this is quite easy with JMockit (you just declare a `@Mocked Beta` or `@Mocked Charlie` field/parameter and then record/verify whichever invocations, regardless of how instances get created in the CUT)... However, I would ask *why mock* anything here in the first place? Keep in mind, mocking is not to be abused. People like Kent Beck (creator of TDD), Martin Fowler, and other "gurus" don't favor mocking (for good reasons).

Comment: I actually have no idea what's the best way to go here. I don't have JMockit set up. Thought this should be straightforward, have limited experience with testing, but have already wasted a few days on it and still can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave my initial answer below if someone find this usefull.

First, put into `Beta` in last line of constructor this:

```
System.out.println("Charlie created: " + this.charlie.hashCode());
```

After running test you will see that charlie is created multiple times.

First when this is called in test:

```
Beta beta = Mockito.spy(alpha.createBeta());
```

and later when this is called:

```
Mockito.when(alpha.createBeta()).thenReturn(beta);
```

So Beta keeps reference to real `Charlie` and because you mocked `createCharlie()`, when you call your code:

```
Assert.assertEquals(special.list, alpha.beta.charlie.list);
```

Real `Charlie` is called, not mocked one. The way how you implemented your classes is not really great, but if I just answer what you should change in test - you should call this instead:

```
Assert.assertEquals(special.list, alpha.beta.createCharlie().list);
```

In that case mocked `Charlie` will be called and the test will pass.

---

Previous answer:

Usually when you unit test something, your focus is on a single testing class. You could use `@Spy`/`@InjectMocks`. When you will test `Beta`, you should mock `Charlie`, when you will test `Alpha`, you will mock `Beta`...

I don't know the purpose but strange in your code is that `createCharlie()` and `randomize()` returns instance of `Charlie`. Anyway, you could lazily create `Charlie` via getter, something like this:

```
public class Beta {
    private Charlie charlie;

    public Beta() {
    }

    public Charlie getCharlie() {
        if (charlie == null) {
            charlie = new Charlie();
        }
        return charlie;
    }

    public void doSomethingWithCharlie() {
        getCharlie().randomize();
    }
}
```

You could inject charlie in your test like this:

```
public class BetaTest{
    @Mock(name="charlie") // variable name in Beta
    private Charlie charlieMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private Beta beta;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void test1(){
        beta.doSomethingWithCharlie();
    }
}
```

See also [@InjectMocks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) documentation.

Optionally you could add package protected/public method to `Alpha`:

```
Beta createBeta() {
    return new Beta(); 
}
```

or

```
Beta getBeta() {
    if(beta==null){
        beta = new Beta();
    }

    return beta;
}
```

Then you could inject into `Alpha` real `Beta` which returns mocked `Charlie`:

public class AlphaTest {
    @Mock
    Charlie charlieMock;

```
@Spy
Beta beta;

@Spy
Alpha alpha;

public void beforeTest() {
    when(alpha.getBeta()).thenReturn(beta);
    when(beta.getCharlie()).thenReturn(charlie);
}
```

}

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20270751/2162924).

Comment: Thanks Dario, perhaps I wasn't clear, I added more info to my question. I agree with testing individual classes but in this case unfortunately, Beta is dependent on Alpha and I can't decouple them. Goal is to verify Alpha/Beta interaction with different Charlies, thats why I want to just mock out the creation of charlie so I can write tests against different instances of Charlie. Hope that clarifies a bit?

Comment: I also appended additional informations to my reply.

Comment: I tried the second approach, didn't work :( - I am not sure what I am missing, this is what I tried before too.

Comment: Use debug and verify that mocks are injected

Comment: Hi Dario, please take another look at the question. That is exact code copied, so you know exactly what I am trying to do. Thank you SO much for taking the time out for this. Really looking forward to your next reply.

Comment: Check edited answer. There is solution for your trouble. You should add more traces, go with debug over and try to understand what was the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that helps definitely. Tests pass and I understand much better how this works now. But now my concern is that I don't want to create charlie when I do `Mockito.when(alpha.createBeta()).thenReturn(beta)`, I want to somehow set it up so that `special` is used when I do `alpha.start()`

Comment: Please see the answer I posted. That solves my problem. Let me know if you have a better way than that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dario's answer, I changed Beta class to

```
public class Beta {
  Alpha alpha;
  Charlie _charlie;

  public Beta(Alpha alpha) {
    this.alpha = alpha;
    this._charlie = getCharlie();
    // PROBLEM: If I use this._charlie here, that will use the wrong charlie!
  }

  Charlie getCharlie() {
    if (_charlie == null) {
      _charlie = new Charlie().shuffle();
    }
    return _charlie;
  }
}
```

Then, I never access charlie with alpha.beta._charlie and always with getCharlie(), that should solve my problem. Thank you Dario, much appreciated!

Comment: Added a comment about problem with this approach. What I really need is to setup my code so that the first getCharlie() call returns the `special` instance.